# Microsoft Jscript runtime error on page redirect - asp.net and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have two pages in my .net website

One is the default.aspx and the other is the login.aspx

default.aspx is just a blank page, which is used for redirecting to the login.aspx page

In login.aspx, I have a textbox and a javascript onfocus event on that texbox. (There is only an alert method in the javascript function)

If I start the login.aspx page from Visual Studio, the page opens up fine in IE and the javascript executes fine on focussing the cursor on the texbox.

If I run the default.aspx from Visual Studio, the page gets redirected to login.aspx. But, the javascript does not execute in this case. i.e. in this case, I get the error - Microsoft jscript runtime error - permission denied'

Not sure what the issue is. If you guys would be able to point anything here, it would be great!!

BTW,

It works fine if debugging is disabled in web.config. Only if debugging is enabled, does this issue crop up.

In firefox, it works absolutely fine. The issue is only with IE.

Thanks!!!

Comment: show your redirect code and your login.aspx javascript.

Comment: Something here is fishy.. can you post screenshot of the error in addition to your code?

Comment: Hi, Since I was not able to post the code in the comments section here, I have added it below. Thanks

Comment: In the future, just edit your original post and add the code there. :)

Comment: Yeah. Nice idea :) Will do so the next time on!!

Answer (score 0):

Please find my code below. Thanks

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.vb

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Session("UserId") Is Nothing Then
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

login.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="login.aspx.vb" Inherits="login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function resetFormField(){alert("OK");}
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtloginemailId" runat="server" Columns="25">                
    </asp:TextBox>
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

login.aspx.vb

```
Partial Class login
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.txtloginemailId.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "resetFormField(this);")
End Sub
End Class
```

(Session has not been set anywhere. So, the redirection would always take place)

Comment: OK, nothing wrong here.. can you please take screenshot of the error, put on some image hosting site and post link here? If not, I must know the following: is this client side script error? Server side?

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of the error. It can be viewed at http://i55.tinypic.com/14jxfyp.jpg. It's not a client side error. Some problem at the server end.

Comment: Gosh! The problem was with the avg antivirus that was running on my comp. On removing it, it's working perfectly fine now!!! Wonder how one is supposed to debug such errors!!! :) Thanks Shadow for looking into it.

Comment: To clarify what happened: the anti virus intervened with the attached debugger, thinking Visual Studio is malicious virus trying to ride the process of the web application, or something along those lines. I wouldn't remove the anti virus completely but mess around with its settings first, maybe you can add Visual Studio to some "white list"..

Comment: Hmm....Yeah. Will try that out. My first aim was in resolving the issue somehow!! :) Thanks.